# Firebase: best practice to display items

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like a suggestion.
I'm developing a web app using react-js as frontend and firebase as backend.

For sake of semplicity, say the aim of the web-app is to allow the user to upload some items which are then displayed on the homepage

An item consists of two string: 1) name of item 2) url pointed to an image stored on IPFS

Once the user submit a form, the frontend creates a new doc in a collection in firestore:

```
await addDoc(collectionRef, newDoc)
```

Then, in the homepage, I display all the items in the collection

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    ...
});
```

This works; however, if I've understood properly, every time the homepage is refreshed the frontend makes `N` **read calls** (where N is the number of docs in the collection). Therefore, I'm wondering if its the right approach, is there a better way?

I really appreaciate any suggestion (also regarding potential major safety flaws in this setting)

Comment: It looks like your client only makes the 1 call to getDocs to get the whole snapshot. This is correct and surely what firebase recommends.

Answer (score 1):

> Every time the homepage is refreshed the frontend makes N read calls
> (where N is the number of docs in the collection).

With `const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);` this is indeed the case: **all the docs in the collection are fetched**.

If your collection contains a lot of documents and is fetched frequently this will cost you money and, at one moment, the performance of you app may be degraded (duration of the Firestore query execution and lot of docs transferred from the back-end to the front-end).

One approach to avoid that is to **use pagination** and fetch only the first X documents and display a link to fetch the X next ones, etc.

There is a [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) in the Firestore documentation dedicated to pagination implementation.

---

You could also implement an infinite scroll mechanism instead of a link, to load the next set of X document continuously as the user scrolls down the page. That's just a UI variation and is based on the exact same approach detailed in the Firestore documentation.

---

> Also regarding potential major safety flaws in this setting

Fetching all the docs of a collection or using pagination does not make any difference in terms of security. In any case you should implement security according to your requirements by using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) (and potentially [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) as well). And don't forget that security [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters).